# Do these sentences have a similar meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Maybe are you able to close the door? = Could you close the door?

I want to know whether the above  sentences have a similar meaning.

Comment: You should be aware that _wanna_ is very informal English, and that _I wanna know_ can sound demanding and rude. _Wanna_ is fine when sending a text message among friends, but you should use the more polite form _Want to_ when requesting help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentences have two different meanings and intentions

> Could you close the door?

Is a direct request for *someone* to close the door, you do not know if it is possible for them to do this.

> Maybe are you able to close the door?
>   *would you be able to close the door?*

Is a request to know if *someone* is able to close the door. The direct request to close the door, if it is possible, is implied, but the listener could very well say they are "able to close the door" without actually closing the door.

Comment: *Maybe are you able to...* is not grammatical English. Leave out the *maybe* and it then means what you said it means.